# Rank of a partitioned matrix with an identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Suppose $X$ is any real-valued rectangular matrix. $C$ is a matrix with zeros and 1s.

How can I show that

$$
Rank
\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
X & I_m - XC \\
\end{array}
\right] = m
$$

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, $m$ is meant to be the number of rows in $X$.

Note that the $m \times n$ matrix $A$ has rank $m$ (full row rank) if and only if $Ax = b$ has a solution for every $b \in \Bbb R^n$.  In this case we note that for any $b$, the vector $x = (Cb,b)$ is such that
$$
\pmatrix{X & I - XC}x = \pmatrix{X & I - XC} \pmatrix{Cb\\ b} = XCB + (I - XC)b = b.
$$
So, your matrix indeed has full row rank.

Answer (score 0):

@Omnomnomnom has given a solution in terms of row-rank $\rho_r$; here's one in terms of column-rank $\rho_c$.

Note that for any matrices $M, N$ each column of the product $MN$ is a linear combination of the columns of $M$. Then by performing column operations we obtain

$$
\rho_c
\begin{bmatrix}
X & I-XC\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\rho_c
\begin{bmatrix}
X & I-XC+XC\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\rho_c
\begin{bmatrix}
X & I\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\rho_c
\begin{bmatrix}
X-IX & I\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\rho_c
\begin{bmatrix}
O & I\\
\end{bmatrix}
=m.
$$